# Read storage data of a "mapping (address => bool)" from another contract

Tags: storage, solidity

I'm trying to read the storage data of another contract, and get all of the addresses in testData:

```
contract XXX {
   mapping (address => bool) public testData;
   ...
}
```

According to the [Mappings and Dynamic Arrays](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/internals/layout_in_storage.html#mappings-and-dynamic-arrays) document, each value is stored with a storage location `keccak256(key)`.

Since this mapping is keyed with address, I'm unable to predicate the key, how can I retrieve all the keys?

Answer (score 0):

Solidity `mapping` is similar to hash maps.

It acts as a pointer to a specific storage location determined by the key (and the property position). But there's no list of used keys, unless you create the list yourself. Example: See `map.keys` [here](https://solidity-by-example.org/app/iterable-mapping/).